# PropertyValuesHolder causes crash when used in XML defined animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to use some `propertyValuesHolder` with an `objectAnimator` in an animation I've defined in XML. When I load it a runtime exception is thrown with the reason `Unknown animator name: propertyValuesHolder`

This is the full animation taken directly from the `ObjectAnimator` docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:repeatCount="1"
            android:repeatMode="reverse">
    <propertyValuesHolder android:propertyName="x" android:valueTo="400"/>
    <propertyValuesHolder android:propertyName="y" android:valueTo="200"/>
</objectAnimator>
```

I'm using the following code to load and start the animation:

```
Animator animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.example);
animator.setTarget(view);
animator.start();
```

The cause I get from the stacktrace is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: propertyValuesHolder
  at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:592)
  at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:551)
  at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:122) 
  at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:102)
  at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:87)
```

This works when I use an animation that doesn't contain a `propertyValuesHolder`. I can't find any examples online where that tag is used in XML. Am I doing something wrong or does it just not work?

Comment: @Shadow Droid Your link 404s. 'Change the code accordingly' based on what? The second example on the ValueAnimator page has an XML defined `propertyValuesHolder` that will cause the same crash

Comment: Sorry for not putting the link properly in previous comment.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html  I do not for what purpose you are using the PropertyValuesHolder...but its actual used to avoid AnimatorSet and make code readable...check this link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html

Comment: I understand it's purpose and I'm using it for such (in the example above to animate the x and y properties of an object over a duration of 1 second). I'm trying to do this in an animation defined in XML not one defined programatically. This should be possible as there are examples of this in the docs (the one I linked to and the one you link to) but an exception is thrown when I try to load it from the XML file

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason is that *propertyValuesHolder* XML element is not supported before Lollipop.

If you take a look at [AnimatorInflater](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android/animation/AnimatorInflater.java/) you will see that first time PropertyValuesHolder class is referenced there is in 5.0.